# Login wont acess (read) my MS SQL Tables which I need for authentication

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

[Here is my MS SQL DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8WeH.png)

[Here is my Java Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1QUU.png)

I have used SQL Server Authentication Login: sa  Password: root

Database is  loaded, but I can not pass login. Probably can not read a table but I don't know why.

Here is my Login Class

```
JLabel lbUsername = new JLabel("Username: ");
JLabel lbPassword = new JLabel("Password: ");
JTextField tfUsername = new JTextField(20);
JPasswordField tfPassword = new JPasswordField(20);
JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Uloguj se");
String loginQuery = "SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD FROM RADNIK";
boolean ulogovan;

public Login() {
    setLayout(new MigLayout("fill"));
    setTitle("Logovanje");
    setSize(250, 150);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel login = new JPanel(new MigLayout("insets 10"));
    login.add(lbUsername);
    login.add(tfUsername, "wrap");
    login.add(lbPassword);
    login.add(tfPassword, "wrap");

    add(login, "dock north, grow");

    JPanel button = new JPanel(new MigLayout("insets 10"));
    button.add(btnLogin, "align center");

    btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (!tfUsername.getText().equals("")
                    && !tfPassword.getPassword().equals("")) {
                String username = tfUsername.getText();
                String password = "";
                for (char ch : tfPassword.getPassword()) {
                    password += ch;
                }
                try {
                    ulogovan = logIn(loginQuery, username, password);
                    if (ulogovan == true) {
                        MainFrame main = new MainFrame();
                        main.setVisible(true);
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane
                                .showMessageDialog(
                                        null,
                                        "Uneli ste neispravno korisnicko ime ili lozinku!",
                                        "Obavestenje",
                                        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

                    }

                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Molimo vas popunite sve podatke!", "Obavestenje",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    });

    add(button, "dock south, grow");
}

public boolean logIn(String sql, String username, String password)
        throws SQLException {
    ArrayList<String> radnici = new ArrayList<String>();
    Statement stmt = DBConnection.getConnection().createStatement();
    ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while (rset.next()) {
        String usernameTemp = rset.getString("USERNAME");
        String passwordTemp = rset.getString("PASSWORD");
        radnici.add(usernameTemp);
        radnici.add(passwordTemp);
    }
    if (radnici.contains(username) && radnici.contains(password)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Database is connected because I get WARNING_MESSAGE "Uneli ste neispravno korisnicko ime ili lozinku!"

Comment: Cannot understand warning message. --- Also, your `logIn` method is horrendous. 1) Why is `sql` a parameter? 2) Adding all user names and passwords to a single collection, then testing for existence, is *very bad*, since anybody can log in by using any valid user name as the password!!!

Comment: Warning message "You have entered an incorrect username or password!".
I got an assignment for college.
I can not change the Database connection.

Comment: Try debugging your code. Put a breakpoint on the `if` statement, and check the content of `radnici` against the values of `username` and `password`.

Comment: Thanks , When I compare the database, my input is normal, but program load from base with Spaces like "aca       " and "aca1      "(it have 7 spaces in base).
Do you have any suggestion how can i fix it? @Andreas

Comment: Either data was inserted with spaces, or you've used `CHAR` data types when you should be using `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I fix it with changing on varchar! @Andreas

Comment: And for heaven's sake you should stop storing passwords in clear text. They should be salted and hashed.